# How try and except work in python during file handling?

Tags: python, try-catch, file-handling

I am curious how this **Try** and **Except** work in python after running into this error:

```
def for_file(data):
    open_file = file('data.txt', 'w')
    try:
        open_file.write(data)
    except:
           print 'This is an error!'
    open_file.close()
```

**Output**: This is an error!

```
def for_file(data):
    try:
        open_file = file('data.txt', 'w')
        open_file.write(data)
        print 'Successful!'
    except:
           print 'This is an error!'
    open_file.close()
```

**Output**: Successful!

How is it possible?

**Error**: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 15-16: ordinal not in range(128)

I am receiving data in unicode form. what should I do?

Comment: Would you add `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` to the `except` clause and add the output to the question?

Comment: What's the error? your `except` block will catch anything.

Comment: I have added that error. data received is in the form of unicode. using str() not helpful..

Comment: @Hemant that doesn't explain why it works in the first example and does not work in the second one. Are you running both snippets with the same data?

Comment: First read *"The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets"* http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write unicode data to a file, use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('data.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a TypeError. When you write to the file, 'data' needs to be a string or buffer. Your second function also won't work if you don't pass it a string or buffer (I tried them both passing them a 2, neither worked). The below code works.

```
 def for_file(data):
    open_file = file('data.txt', 'w')
    try:
        open_file.write(str(data))
        print "Success!"
    except:
        import traceback; traceback.print_exc() #I used this to find the error thrown.
        print 'This is an error!'
    open_file.close()
```

Comment: If "neither worked", you didn't reproduce the OP's situation.

Comment: OP didn't inform us as to what input he used for either. I just kind of assumed he changed between the two. If not, (i.e. he passed a string) then both should have worked. I can't do anything more without his input.

Comment: @NightHallow: Yup u r right. I am getting data in unicode form. str() not working..

Answer (score 0):

You may need to print the error message to figure out what's the problem:

```
def for_file(data):
    open_file = file('data.txt', 'w')
    try:
        open_file.write(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'This is an error!'
        print e
    open_file.close()
```